# Is it possible to compile 'c-mex' with openMP by the free compiler?

Tags: c, matlab, openmp, mex

I'm learning how to use mex file in matlab.

I currently using **MATLAB R2016a** on **Windows 10**.

I tried to use OpenMP like this

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <omp.h>

void mexFunction ( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    int nthreads,tid;
    #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        if(tid==0){
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            mexPrintf("Number of Threads : %d\n",nthreads);
        }
        mexPrintf("Echo from %d\n",tid);

    }
    return;
}
```

It works well if I use **Visual Studio Professional 2015**.

However, if I use **MinGW64 Compiler**, it does not work.

Then I found that there are some compiler which do not provide openMP feature.

Is there any **free** compiler that supports `mex` and `omp`??

Comment: Most versions of mingw64, clang, and all cygwin are built with --enable-libgomp or equivalent  even though a few features of libgomp aren't available for windows.  Static link may not be available.